# Handbag question

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

One day, you are shopping in a town. You came across a handbag you wanted to buy. The handbag costs ? coins. It is said that solving a logic question could earn you enough coins to buy the handbag.


a = 2, b = 56

- 5 = a0
- 6 = 30
- 7 = 4a
- 8 = b
- 9 = 7a
- 11 = ?

Question: How many ? coins can you get? (There are 4 different answers to this question. Find all 4 possible answers to this riddle.)

First answer has been [found](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/112650).

There are still 3 other possible answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four answers:

1. > 110 if pattern is n(n-1) because 11*10=110
2. > 99 if pattern is n*(previous n) because 11*9=99
3. > 2 if pattern is sum of digits squared - sum of digits because (1+1) squared - (1+1) = 2
4. > 0 if pattern is digits of n individually multiplied by digits of n-1 individually because 1 x 1 x 1 x 0 = 0

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm missing something? If $a=2$ and $b=56$, then the pattern seems trivial:

> 5 = 20: multiply by 4.
>  6 = 30: multiply by 5.
>  7 = 42: multiply by 6.
>  8 = 56: multiply by 7.
>  9 = 72: multiply by 8.
>  10 = 90: multiply by 9.
>  11 = 110: multiply by 10.

So the answer should be

> 110.

Comment: That is correct. Now there is another 3 possible answers to this question.